# How does mongodb authentication and Connection string work?

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, connection-string

**My scenario**: I have a mongodb instance running, with following database:

```
> show dbs
admin                 0.000GB
config                0.000GB
local                 0.000GB
event-service         0.000GB
```

I also created some users.

When I log in to mongo and check existing users, here's the result:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.system.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "admin.admin",
    "userId" : UUID("0e41bcf5-9cdc-4fe5-8989-7db842cb3f1a"),
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : 10000,
            "salt" : "5BN0tb2b68yNMpRywAkj+w==",
            "storedKey" : "9MVDlhYob4C2jcySGQrZKIj71NQ=",
            "serverKey" : "U2CB/y/Mkubqm6J0w6pNfQFACV0="
        },
        "SCRAM-SHA-256" : {
            "iterationCount" : 15000,
            "salt" : "iDfSw3i7STGdlS0gqxIWylJVQebW53YOUri39w==",
            "storedKey" : "xHXZYpz03tR2XS+dVa/lTBs+hzkF6lSd2xUmib8H0S4=",
            "serverKey" : "OsjxxEc/f3KOlGdqyJ4N5/UyhzJts9ycVZsEOS4cxrA="
        }
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbAdmin",
            "db" : "event-service"
        },
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
{
"_id" : "event-service.eventadmin",
"userId" : UUID("c3e35487-4af1-448c-93cc-b1a83920949b"),
"user" : "eventadmin",
"db" : "event-service",
"credentials" : {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
        "iterationCount" : 10000,
        "salt" : "l0qqUmFl+74gh/EdAGdOcQ==",
        "storedKey" : "IS4lmKjzb0+sDoKWc2hcO8YIZ8w=",
        "serverKey" : "xXVTDAilaMVShGmUo19UatdexYs="
    },
    "SCRAM-SHA-256" : {
        "iterationCount" : 15000,
        "salt" : "JinBcUBW7V539Go/gKr9s6Vi15EJCNJRMQQnpQ==",
        "storedKey" : "nX48I9NaSqrUD1RphTXmNDhHn1K1OZkVK8mzPHaBh5Y=",
        "serverKey" : "K7qtrFivxRb6JDGruqYB9ETBbzpBg2zrgEo9cqCeX7k="
    }
},
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "dbAdmin",
        "db" : "event-service"
    }
]
}
```

When I enable authentication for mongodb with `--auth` option and try to login with `mongo -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase event-service`, it says

> Error: Authentication failed

**My questions:**

1. Why does it fail to authenticate against "event-service" db, even when the "admin" user has the role dbAmin on it?
2. As I understand, this command

> mongo -u eventadmin -p admin --authenticationDatabase event-service

will login to mongodb, use default "test" db. And it is equivalent to this connection string

> spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://eventadmin:admin@localhost:27017/event-service

. Is that correct?

3. If 2/ is correct, what's the connection string that is equivalent to this command ?

> mongo -u eventAdmin -p admin --authenticationDatabase event-service event-service

What I want is that after my services successfully access to mongodb with this connection string, it will automatically connect to the "event-service" db, instead of the default "test" db.